# Count how many occurrences of value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset in Python and a column which lists the type of loan applicant (individual, couple, business etc) and i am trying to find out how many of each applicant there are.  i am new to Python and this is probably a very basic question. any feedback is appreciated

i tried:

`df['applicant_type'].count()` = only provided the total number of data in column

```
df['applicant_type'].head()
df['applicant_type'].info()
df['applicant_type'].dict()
```

none of the above worked

Comment: What does the data inside df look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['applicant_type'].value_counts()
```